# How to easily switch keyboards on Android 9 (MIUI)

Tags: keyboard

My old phone (Android 8 I believe) showed a little icon on bottom right side to allow switching keyboards, from Gboard to Hackers' keyboard or else.
[image: Android 8 keyboard]

My new phone on Android 9 (also a new brand, Xiaomi, MIUI) after installing several keyboards, does not show the switch. [image: Android 9 keyboard]

Does someone know how to switch keyboards easily on Xiaomi's Android 9 (as I could do previously on older Android) without having to go everytime into Configuration menus.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthustiasts! Are the other keyboard enabled?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am able to switch keyboards from the configuration menu unless I misunderstood what enabled is.

Answer (score 1):

**To switch between different languages in Gboard** (keyboard visible in the screenshot in the question) —

- Long press on the spacebar
  (In much older versions of Gboard, you could also switch between different installed keyboards this way, but that feature disappeared long back.)
- Use the language switch key (the globe-like icon on the left of the spacebar)

**To switch to another installed keyboard** —

- Go to Settings → Additional Settings → Languages & Input → Current Keyboard → Choose Keyboards
- Make sure that the keyboard that you want to use is enabled.
  [image: Enable keyboard in settings]
- Now, navigate to any text input and start typing with your current keyboard
- You should see a notification from Android System, that says *Choose keyboard*
  (Note: This notification lasts only until your current keyboard is open, so you have to open the notification panel, without closing the keyboard, to see this notification.)
  [image: Choose keyboard notification]
- Tap on this notification and you should be able to choose your other keyboard in the menu
  [image: Choose keyboard menu]

Comment: I think the second part of your answer is what the OP asked.

Comment: I thought the same, but I mentioned both, just to be clear.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I did not know about the notification to change keyboard, that worked here. A thousand thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

[image]

First, you go to Settings > Apps > Manage Apps > Select 3 dots on the top right corner > Show All Apps.
Then find the Android System, search notification name "Virtual Keyboard."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the option to switch keyboards because **I forgot that I blocked the notification for keyboard input.** I fixed it by following these steps:

- Go to Settings > Apps > Manage Apps
- Tap on the three dots on the top right corner and select Show All Apps
- Find and tap on Android System
- Tap on Notifications and scroll down to Virtual Keyboard
- Enable the notifications for Virtual Keyboard

Answer (score -1):

Long press space. All keyboard options will display. Choose the one you want.